# Make cv.glmnet select something between lambda.min and lambda.1se

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

I'm training an Elastic Net model and am finding that `lambda.1se` is much higher than `lambda.min`, often the maximum lambda tested with zero features selected. I'm guessing that this is because my standard deviations are really large.

Is there a way to make `cv.glmnet` select a value somewhere between `lambda.1se` and `lambda.min`?

```
x = matrix(rnorm(100 * 20), 100, 20) # not the actual data
y = gl(2, 50)

fit <- cv.glmnet(
  x = x, y = y,
  family = "binomial",
  nfolds = nrow(x), grouped = F,
  standardize = T,
  alpha = 0.2
)
```

Comment: There's a set of ``lambda`` values that you can use in ``fit$lambda``. If ``lambda.1se`` is too sparse, you might want to select lambda based on ``fit$nzero``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Nutle, I was able to use your advice to implement a selection function similar to the `tolerance` function in `caret`. It selects the largest value of lambda within a percent difference of the minimum error.

```
get_lambda <- function(fit, tol = 1.05) {
  error <- fit$cvm[fit$lambda == fit$lambda.min]
  tolerance <- error * tol
  max(fit$lambda[fit$cvm <= tolerance])
}
```